# Se existir atualiza uma tabela e insere em outra, se não, insere nas duas

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Como fazer uma expressão utilizando **EF** para que, quando uma determinada lista de objetos seja enviado e já existir no banco de dados, ele seja atualizado e a alteração seja inserida em uma outra entidade de histórico, caso contrario, insere nas duas entidades.

## Exemplo

```
 public void Insere(List<T> objeto)
{
  using (Context ctx = new Context())
  {
    
     if(objeto.Select(x => x.Id).Intersect(ctx.Entidade.Select(x => x.Id)).Any() > 0){
      //Atualizo apenas os registros existentes e insiro no histórico (Para cada item da lista)
     } 

      //Insiro os registros inexistentes e insiro no histórico (Para cada item da lista) 
  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já existe isso. É a extensão [`AddOrUpdate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520(v=vs.103).aspx).

Uso:

```
ctx.Entidade.AddOrUpdate(e => e.Id, objetos);
```

O primeiro campo é o campo que o Entity Framework fará para verificar se o registro existe ou não. No exemplo, verificará por Id. Se o Id não existe, insere. Caso contrário, atualiza.

Comment: Qual a versão do EF, tem essa extensão?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Ao que eu saiba, desde o EF 5.